# Binary output in Windows

Tags: c, windows, file-io, stdio

I wrote a program that reads a binary file, does some process with its contents and writes the results to a different file. In Linux it works perfectly, but in Windows it does not work; the output files are always 1KB...

This is a simplified version of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void copyFile(char* source, char* dest);

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
        printf ("usage: %s <source> <destination>", argv[0]);
    else
    {
        copyFile(argv[1], argv[2]);
    }
}


void encryptFile(char* source, char* destination)
{
    FILE *sourceFile;
    FILE *destinationFile;

    int fileSize;

    sourceFile = fopen(source, "r");
    destinationFile = fopen(destination, "w");

    if (sourceFile == 0)
    {
        printf ("Could not open source file\n");
        return;
    }

    if (destinationFile == 0)
    {
        printf ("Could not open destination file\n");
        return;
    }

    // Get file size
    fseek(sourceFile, 0, SEEK_END); // Seek to the end of the file
    if (ftell(sourceFile) < 4) 
        return; // Return if the file is less than 4 bytes
    fseek(sourceFile, 0, SEEK_SET); // Seek back to the beginning

    fseek(sourceFile, 0, SEEK_SET); // Seek back to the beginning

    int currentChar;

    while ((currentChar = fgetc(sourceFile)) != EOF)
    {
            fputc(currentChar, destinationFile);
    }

    fclose(sourceFile);
    fclose(destinationFile);
}
```

I would love to give you more details of the problem, but I don't have much experience programming C in Windows and I really don't know where may be the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the `b` flag to fopen:

```
fopen(source, "rb")
fopen(destination, "wb");
```

I understand that due to some (<strike>brain-damage</strike>) subjective decisions, on win32 reaching 0x1A on the input stream triggers an `EOF` if the file is not opened in "binary mode".

**EDIT**

In never looked into it but somebody is telling me now that `0x1A` was used in DOS as a soft EOF.

Comment: It's probably more brain damage then subjective - the reason for the eof character is due to Windows' prehistoric connection with CP/M which only kept track of a file's size at a sector (or cluster?) granularity.

Comment: @Michael Burr I would really like it if you had more info on that.

Comment: There's not much more info - CP/M only knew how many sectors a text file occupied on disk; to know when it should stop reading data from the last sector a sentinel EOF value was used, and they chose `ctrl-Z` to be that sentinel.  Since MS-DOS provided some level of compatibility with CP/M, it supported the same scheme. And since Windows pulled in a lot of DOS baggage, here we are.

Comment: A note about the answer: the destination file also needs the `"b"` flag or binary writes will be corrupted on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you're not opening the files in binary mode (use "wb" and "rb").  This doesn't matter on Linux, but it does on Windows, which will transform certain bytes when reading/writing a file in text mode.  For example:

```
\r\n <--> \n 

\x1a  (Ctrl-Z) is treated as an EOF indicator
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "rb" and "wb" with fopen.